# Adding local import statements if module is being run by itself

Tags: python, python-2.7, module

I have a class that is used in my web application with parameters that are passed in from the user. lets take this example for instance:

```
class SomeObject():
    def __init__(self, param1, param2, logger_object):
        logger_object.log("init...")
        self.param1 = param1
        self.param2 = param2
```

Now I need the option to make an instance of that class in headless mode (so I can automatically run it via Jenkins).

So I know I can use this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger = initialising logger # question about this later
    param1 = "param1"
    param2 = "param2"
    some_object = SomeObject(param1, param2, logger)
```

and my question is this:
is this the right/pythonic way to do this?  or I'm better off making a different class and inheriting from SomeObject?

Also, the current file does not import the logger module, because usually it does not need it. I don't want to import that module for no reason, so I thought may be doing this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from logger.location import logger
    logger = logger()
    param1 = "param1"
    param2 = "param2"
    some_object = SomeObject(param1, param2, logger)
```

But I'm not sure that this is recommended as well. Thoughts/ideas?

Comment: This would ba a non-issue if this were a script that imports `SomeObject` from another module and then creates an instance. Why can't you do just that?

Comment: it just seemed like it would be more readable in the same file. but thats what I ended up doing